# Is it wise to use compressed NTFS Windows Vmware stored on a compressed NTFS drive?

Tags: windows, ntfs, vmware, compression

I have a **Windows 10 vmware box** stored on a **compressed NTFS drive**.

So, my question is whether it's a good idea to use compressed NTFS on the "C:" drive of the **Windows 10 vmware box** *(i.e. compressed NTFS inside another compressed NTFS)* ?

Answer (score 0):

Hard drives are cheap.  Your time is not.  Every time that data is read or written it takes time and electricity and heats up your office / home.  I suggest buying a large hard drive and dedicating it to your virtual machines.  It's also worthwhile having an old PC with big hard drives which does nothing but accept automatic backups from your modern PCs.

Comment: Thanks but my question is more concerned with the idea I mentioned previously rather than HDD itself. I do know it'd be better not to use compressed NTFS but the purpose is to know whether using compressed NTFS VMD stored on compressed NTFS drive has critical cons or useful advantages.

Comment: The con is mostly wasted time.  I suppose it's harder to recover in the event of physical hard drive crash but those are very hard to recover from in the first place.

Comment: If you have a reason to test it out, by all means, think it out scientifically, make some separated test cases, and gather some data.  I suspect you will find it's slow and doesn't save you any more disk space than 1 layer of NFTS compression.

Comment: Thanks. However, 2 layers of NTFS did actually save me extra gigabytes despite a minor setback in performance. This may due to the fact that VMware Disk File is not fully compressible from the layer outside but from the inside it seems all files are directly accessible and so it's more compressible.

Answer (score 0):

No, either compress inside the VM or outside.  Compressing both on the host and guest will almost always waste a significant amount of processing power.

In a vast majority of cases, you will be better off compressing outside the VM than inside.  This is because of a combination of fewer context switches potentially prolonging the time it takes to compress, and the fact that it will also compress the volume's metadata (which NTFS compression does not normally do).

The one case where it's better to compress inside instead of outside is if you're using full disk encryption *inside* the guest itself.  In this case, compressing on the host will waste time and save you essentially nothing (properly encrypted data does not compress well), so if you want to save disk space you need to use a dynamically allocated disk image format on the host, and compress inside the guest.

Comment: Guess you are right, however, I would recommend to use NTFS inside the VM not the opposite since VMware itself saves a bunch of information outside the VM including logs and vmem (virtual memory file), I've noticed that it takes much more time to save a virtual machine or restore it. It also comes to the encryption you mentioned which would waste any compression. I guess what it boils down to is that it's not recommended to use NTFS on an operation system drive.